Why is Macbook Pro 2019 with Intel & T2 NOT recognizing live USB for dual booting Linux using T2Linux ISO image?
Macbook Pro 2019 is NOT recognizing live USB for dual booting linux using https://t2linux.org ISO image
If I use 'Option' key, it will just show the single option, Macintosh HD and boot into MacOS
Without 'Option' key it will just boot into grub console, and, if I enter 'exit'
grub > exit

It will again boot into MacOS.
grub> ls
grub> ls (hd0): 

Device hd0: Filesystem type: iso9660 – label ‘t2linux-fedora-live-39’ – last modification time: 2024-12-04 00 31:55 Monday, UUID: 2023-12-04-00-31-35-00 – Sector size 512B – Total size 15240576KiB

grub> set root=(hd0)

grub> chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
ERROR file ‘/efi/boot/bootx64.efi’ not found

grub> boot
ERROR: you need to load the kernel first

What should I do?

You can see a grub prompt? Unless you have grub installed on your Mac's HD then it sounds like the USB actually is booting, only it's misconfigured somehow. Maybe test it on another computer, make sure you have a good working USB that will boot to whatever menu it's supposed to / you want

@Xen2050
Edited the post

Yeah, that definitely looks like the USB is being recognized and booting, so at least that isn't the main problem. The USB however isn't working properly (they almost always have nice menu's, so you don't have to type long arcane lines manually). I'd try using a different method to create another bootable USB, and try to confirm it works on another computer just in case. I don't know if it's an issue with the method/program that "wrote" the USB, or the distro, or the ISO itself, but I'd try a few changes until finding some that work together. IDK, Ubuntu usually supports lots of hardware?
